# Is gwt ae limited on memory usage?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

How match memory can use GWT in AppEngine? Can this limit be changed? Is it limit for user session or for all application? How can I test my application behavior before deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT runs on the client side, not on the server side, so server memory limitations do not apply.